# React function component setTimeout - Multiple render calls and rerenders (recommended approach) (fires multiple times)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Notification component that should close itself after a few seconds and call the `onClose` prop:

```js
function Notification(props) {
  console.log("Notification function component called");
  setTimeout(() => {
    props.onClose();
  }, 4000);
  return (
    <div>
      {props.children}
      <button onClick={props.onClose}>Close</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In my App, I have a state that holds notifications object and I map through them.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.pushNotification = this.pushNotification.bind(this);
  }
  state = {
    notifications: {}
  };
  pushNotification() {
    const id = uuid();
    const newNotifications = { ...this.state.notifications };
    const date = new Date();
    newNotifications[id] = {
      id,
      date: JSON.stringify(date)
    };
    this.setState({
      notifications: newNotifications
    });
  }
  removeNotification(id) {
    console.log("removeNotification");
    const newNotifications = { ...this.state.notifications };
    delete newNotifications[id];
    this.setState({
      notifications: newNotifications
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={this.pushNotification}>Push notification</button>
        {Object.keys(this.state.notifications).map(
          (notificationIndexKey, index) => {
            return (
              <Notification
                originalKey={JSON.stringify(index)}
                key={notificationIndexKey}
                onClose={() => {
                  console.log("Notfication fired on close");
                  this.removeNotification(notificationIndexKey);
                }}
              >
                Notification{" "}
                {this.state.notifications[notificationIndexKey].date}
              </Notification>
            );
          }
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I've noticed that if I push multiple notifications in my state, the setTimout is initialized multiple times (which makes sense since render it's called every time the state is updated)

My question is, how would you recommend optimizing this so that the timeout to be invoked only once.

One method that I've tried is to create an array with items that I've removed and check before I call the prop.

Sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/6y3my2y2jr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should apply that side-effect when the component has mounted.
Currently your code will do this on render. 
The render function can be called multiple times.

This code should reflect the correct changes.

```js
class Notification extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(this.props.onClose, 4000);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       {props.children}
       <button onClick={props.onClose}>Close</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice! This works. I did not want to convert the functional component to a class, but I think this looks cleaner. Thank you/Multumeeesc Codrin!

Comment: Or you could do a simple react hook. This will not require the Notification component to become a class.
```useEffect(() => { 
   const timer = setTimeout(props.onClose, 4000)
   return () => clearTimeout(timer)
}, [])
```
The `[]` means that it will get executed once, and the function it returns will be executed when the components unmounts.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by keeping a class property say `notificationTimer` initially set to null and can modify your Notification functions as:

```
function Notification(props) {
  console.log("Notification function component called");

  if (!this.notificationTimer)
    this.notificationTimer = setTimeout(() => {
      props.onClose();
    }, 4000);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {props.children}
      <button onClick={props.onClose}>Close</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And in your close function you can do something like this:

```
onClose() {
  // Your code.

  if (this.notificationTimer) {
    clearTimeout(this.notificationTimer);
    this.notificationTimer = null;
  }
}
```

This will not let you create multiple timers.

Comment: Sound like a very good idea, except that Notification function is a react component and it does not have `this` related to the App code. I would also like to be able to use that component outside the App as well.

Comment: Well, in Angular, we achieve this by having a separate service for Notifications and that service holds the references to the timers.

Comment: Thank you @Pratyush, sounds good, will try some other thoughts and will let you know